# how to delete computer account from Active Directory using c#

Tags: c#, active-directory

Is there any sample that deletes computer account from AD using C#?

I have searched many sources, but all are about user account.

added my code here, i always got errors for some reason.

```
public static bool checkExistingPC(string compName,string userName,string userPwd )
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://test.com",userName,userPwd,AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
        DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
       mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=computer)(|(cn=" + compName + ")(dn=" + compName + ")))";
       foreach (SearchResult result in mySearcher.FindAll())
       {
           if (result != null)
           {

               MessageBox.Show("computer GetDirectoryEntry():" + result.Path+"\n"+"computer path: "+result.Path);
                DirectoryEntry entryToRemove = new DirectoryEntry(result.Path,userName,userPwd);
                 entry.Children.Remove(entryToRemove);

               return true;
           }
           else
           {
               return false;
           }
       }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @Oli: Active Directory, Microsoft's directory service for Windows http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory

Comment: Have you tried entryToRemove.DeleteTree();  ?

Comment: Also after DeleteTree try entryToRemove.CommitChanges(); Ensure you are only deleting the computer entry and NOT something else :D

Comment: as i understand that DeleteTree will delete anything within object container...i havent tried it, cuz i feel it's little risk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using ADSI which is under `System.DirectoryServices` use a commit mechanism, here is a working sample :

```
/* Retreiving RootDSE infos
 */
string ldapBase = "LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/";
string sFromWhere = ldapBase + "rootDSE";
DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry(sFromWhere, "dom\\jpb", "PWD");
string defaultNamingContext = root.Properties["defaultNamingContext"][0].ToString();

/* Retreiving the computer to remove
 */
sFromWhere = ldapBase + defaultNamingContext;
DirectoryEntry deBase = new DirectoryEntry(sFromWhere, "dom\\jpb", ".biènèsph^r^.1966");

DirectorySearcher dsLookForDomain = new DirectorySearcher(deBase);
dsLookForDomain.Filter = "(&(cn=MACHSUPR))"; // MACHSUPR is the computer to delete
dsLookForDomain.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
dsLookForDomain.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
dsLookForDomain.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");

SearchResultCollection srcComputer = dsLookForDomain.FindAll();

foreach (SearchResult aComputer in srcComputer)
{
  /* For each computer
   */
  DirectoryEntry computerToDel = aComputer.GetDirectoryEntry();
  computerToDel.DeleteTree();
  computerToDel.CommitChanges();
}
```

Comment: thanks, i managed to make it work based on the code you provide.

Answer (score 5):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up (if you're not - time to upgrade!), you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find the computer in question
ComputerPrincipal computer = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "NAME");

// if found - delete it
if (computer != null)
{
   computer.Delete();
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users, computers and groups in AD!

Comment: If different credentials are needed, it's possible to create the `PrincipalContext` with username/password. Example: `new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain.net", "DC=domain,DC=net", ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.Signing | ContextOptions.Sealing, "domain\\username", "mySecretPassword")`

Answer (score 0):

Use WMI and or `System.DirectoryServices` namespace (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx).

Comment: Have a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.computerprincipal.aspx

Answer (score -1):

It may not be exactly what you are looking for, but [this site](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx) provides a number of code examples for working with AD in C#, including deleting a security group and removing a user from a group

Comment: thanks, but i found that website has no info about computer accounts